# Wordpress; getting posts from a different site in a multisite within a filter

Tags: wordpress, multisite, acfpro

I am trying to populate an ACF select with posts from a different site in multisite.

This code works in the context of a single site (ie by removing `switch_to_blog`) but doesn't work with the switch - no error simply returns no posts. Is there a reason that `switch_to_blog` can't be used in this context and is there another way of retrieving posts from another blog.

My code:

```
function acf_load_cta_posts( $field ) {
  // reset choices
  $field['choices'] = array();

  switch_to_blog(1);
  $args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'cta',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  );

  $cta_query = new WP_Query($args);

  while ($cta_query->have_posts()) : $cta_query->the_post();
    // vars
    $value = get_the_ID();
    $label = get_the_title();
    // append to choices
    $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;

  endwhile;

  if (empty($field['choices']) ) {
    $field['choices'][0] = "No CTA posts found";
  }

  wp_reset_postdata();
  restore_current_blog();

  // return the field
  return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=cta_choice', 'acf_load_cta_posts', 999, 1);
```